# Sortby in Javardd

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm usinig spark with java. And i want to sort my map. In fact, i have i javaRDD like this :

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> rebondCountURL = session_rebond_2.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, String>, String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, String> call(Tuple2<String, String> stringStringTuple2) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<String, String>(stringStringTuple2._2, stringStringTuple2._1);
        }
    }).groupByKey().map(new PairFunction<Tuple2<String, Iterable<String>>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(Tuple2<String, Iterable<String>> stringIterableTuple2) throws Exception {
            Iterable<String> strings = stringIterableTuple2._2;
            List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String s : strings) {
                b.add(s);
            }
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(stringIterableTuple2._1, b.size());
        }
    });
```

And i want to sort this Java Rdd using Sortby (in order to sort using the Integer).

Can you help me please to do it ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a function which extracts the sorting key from each element. Example from our code

```
final JavaRDD<Something> stage2 = stage1.sortBy( new Function<Something, Long>() {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public Long call( Something value ) throws Exception {
    return value.getTime();
  }
}, true, 1 );
```

Comment: This worked for me too.. For beginners like me, the above function sorts according to the time.. Just wanted to know how does the number of partitions affect the sort?

Comment: This parameter controls how many parallel tasks would execute the sort. The next processing level would get, as input, this amount of partitions. For example, if this parameter is set to 10 and the next processing level saves the RDD to a file, 10 output files would be created.

Comment: Would increasing the number of partitions have the partitions be created using the sortKey and not affect the global sort order?

Comment: @Notinlist Is `stage1` an RDD (Scala) object? As I do not find [sortBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#sortBy) in [JavaRDD API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html).

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ Probably I was talking about 1.1.0 (released @ 2014-09-11), but I don't remember exactly. https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#sortBy(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function,%20boolean,%20int)

Comment: for completion, in Java8, I believe it is something like: `stage2 = stage1.sortBy((Something value) -> value.getTime() , true, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip related to sortBy().. If you want to sort a set of user defined objects say Point then implement the Comparable<Point> interface in the class Point and override the compareTo() method in which you can write your own logic for sorting. After this, the sortby function will take care of the sorting logic.

Note: your Point class must also implement java.io.Serializable interface or else you will encounter NotSerializable exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is a code based on @Vignesh suggestion. You can `sortBy` any custom implementation of `Comparator`. It is more clean to write the comparator separately, and use a reference in the spark code :

```
 rdd ->{JavaRDD<MaxProfitDto> result = 
        rdd.keyBy(Recommendations.profitAsKey)
        .sortByKey(new CryptoVolumeComparator())
        .values()
```

So, the comparator looks like below:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Comparator;

import models.CryptoDto;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class CryptoVolumeComparator implements Comparator<Tuple2<BigDecimal, CryptoDto>>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public int compare(Tuple2<BigDecimal, CryptoDto> v1, Tuple2<BigDecimal, CryptoDto> v2) {
        return  v2._1().compareTo(v1._1());
    }
}
```